# Nginx ssl termination and ssl_preread

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ejabberd

I'm trying to use nginx to reverse proxy both an xmpp and an http connection, having the same port, same ip, same server name in such a way that:

- http connections to https://example.com:443/ are proxied to localhost:8080
- XMPP connections to example.com:443 are proxied to localhost:5222

This is working perfectly if I don't enable SSL termination.

The logic works by leveraging `ssl_preread`, and `ssl_preread_alpn_protocols` variables but when I enable ssl termination, the `ssl_preread_*` variables are always empty.

In other words:

- `listen 443 ssl;` works, because `ssl_preread_alpn_protocols` is different between xmpp calls and http calls
- `listen 443 ssl;` does not work, because `ssl_preread_alpn_protocols` is always empty

Following, an abstract of the configuration:

```
stream  {
    map $ssl_preread_alpn_protocols $upstream_by_alpn {
        "" xmpp;
        ~xmpp xmpp;
        default http;
    }
    upstream xmpp   {
        server 127.0.0.1:5222;
    }
    upstream http   {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }
    server  {
        listen 443 ssl; #listen 443; works / listen 443 ssl; does not work
        ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
        proxy_pass $upstream_by_alpn;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
http {
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 8443;
        location /  {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to make `ssl_preread_*` variables work when the `ssl` directive is applied?
- Is there a better way to identify http and non-http requests?
- Is there a better approach to proxy pass http and xmpp and enable ssl offload and keeping the same server, ip and port?

PS: I know that by using a different port or domain i wouldn't have such problems, but this is not an option for now.

Tried to use the ssl_preread_protocol, ssl_preread_alpn_protocols, ssl_preread_server_name but it's always empty, when the ssl termination is enabled.

Tried to use the $protocol, but it's always TCP

Answer (score 0):

I never set up xmpp, but I think you need to enable SSL on the destination server, not during ClientHello. Here's what the [official Nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html) says about it:

> The ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module module (1.11.5) allows extracting
> information from the ClientHello message without terminating SSL/TLS,
> for example, the server name requested through SNI or protocols
> advertised in ALPN.

It turns out that the ssl directive and certificates must be removed from the stream and used in the http block.

```
stream  {
    map $ssl_preread_alpn_protocols $upstream_by_alpn {
        "" xmpp;
        ~xmpp xmpp;
        default http;
    }
    upstream xmpp   {
        server 127.0.0.1:5222;
    }
    upstream http   {
        server 127.0.0.1:8443;
    }
    server  {
        listen 443; #listen 443;
        proxy_pass $upstream_by_alpn;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}
http {
    server {
        server_name example.com;
        listen 8443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
        location /  {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to enable ssl on the xmpp server.